# onClickItem ListView custom ArrayAdapter Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to touch a listItem from my listView and detect the touch (and get which listItem was touched) because after that I'm going to show a new Activity with the information of the post.

But I'm having problems because I don't know how to do it and also I tried a lot of different tutorials and codes and it's never working in my case, and that's why I'm going to post my full code because I'm out of options right now.

That's my code:

```
public class Blog extends AppCompatActivity {

// URL
String url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/";

// Key JSON
String keyJSON = "posts";

// Construct the data source
ArrayList<Blog> array = new ArrayList<Blog>();

// Background color action bar
String actionBarBackgroundColor = "#00b7bb";

// Title action bar
String actionBarTitle = "Blog";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blog);

    // Action Bar
    setupActionBar(actionBarBackgroundColor, actionBarTitle);

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    final BlogAdapter adapter = new BlogAdapter(this, array);

    // Load posts
    initBlog(adapter);
}

// Action Bar
public void setupActionBar(String color, String titulo) {
    // Create Action bar
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // Display title
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titulo);

    // Action bar background
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(color)));

    // Show back arrow
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

// Get the information and display it in the ListView
private void initBlog(final BlogAdapter adapter) {

    // List View
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Click","Click");
        }
    });

    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                //Show result
                //Log.d("Result", jsonResponse.toString());

                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(keyJSON);

                // Create products
                for(int i = 0; i<jsonMainNode.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String titulo = jsonChildNode.getString("title");
                    String fecha = jsonChildNode.getString("fecha");
                    String imagen = jsonChildNode.getString("imagen");
                    String introtext = jsonChildNode.getString("introtext");
                    String fulltext = jsonChildNode.getString("fulltext");

                    Blog newPost = new Blog(titulo, fecha, imagen, introtext, fulltext);

                    adapter.add(newPost);
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", error.toString());
        }
    });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}

// Back arrow action
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuPrincipal.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    return true;
}
}
```

List View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:context=".Blog.Blog"
>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10px">
</ListView>
```

List Item View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="0px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_fecha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blog_image"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_intro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Ver post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:background="@color/color"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20px"
            android:paddingRight="20px"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

BlogAdapter:

```
public class BlogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blog> {

public BlogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Blog> blogs) {
    super(context, 0, blogs);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Get the data item for this position
    Blog blog = getItem(position);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_item, parent, false);
    }


    TextView blogTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
    TextView blogFecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.blog_fecha);
    ImageView blogImagen = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);
    TextView blogIntrotext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.blog_intro);

    blogTitulo.setText(blog.titulo);
    blogFecha.setText(blog.fecha);
    blogIntrotext.setText(blog.introtext);

    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(blog.imagen).into(blogImagen);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: Post Your Logcat error, post your custom adapter code as well.

Comment: You have to implement OnItemClickListener on your ListView.

Comment: Can you show me how @vidulaJ? I have tried a lot of different codes but none of them is working. I will really appreciate if you can show me some code or a good tutorial to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all make your **class Parcelable or Serializable** 
>   You need to add the `ItemClickListener` to your `listview`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Blog.this,ActivityToOpen.class);
                intent.putParcelable("BlogModeKey",array.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

and read that object in ActivityToOpen.

**Note**
or send each Blog model attribute one by one using putExtra

And don't use same name for model Class and Activity

Comment: Hi @AabidMulani, I have copied and pasted your code after my declaration of listView and it's not working (inside the initBlog function). Why it's not working? Thanks

Comment: Can you update the Code Snippet in the question accordingly

Comment: Done, I have updated the first post with your code and the "Log" is never called when I touch the list item. Thanks @AabidMulani

Comment: Is there any issue with the layout. Are you sure that the List item is clickable. (Note that there is no other layout above the listview which is blocking the click for the listview)

Comment: I'm going to add my 2 layouts and I hope you can find something. Thanks @AabidMulani

Answer (score 1):

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
//Write code
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Array` of `Blog` when you extract `JSON` response and then initialize the `Adapter` with the `Array`. Then set the `Adapter` to the `ListView`.

Here,

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++){
    ......
    Blog newPost = new Blog(titulo, fecha, imagen, introtext, fulltext);
    array.add(newPost);
}
```

Then,

```
if(array.size() > 0){
    adapter = new BlogAdapter(this, array);

    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Blog blog = array[position];//You have the Blog Object here
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi @vidulaJ, I'm trying to follow your code but the OnItemClickListener is still not called.

Comment: What do you mean by not calling? Event happens or a text in Log Cat is not there?

Comment: The event did not happen. But I have already solved it and it was because I had to add android:focusable="false" in my layout. Thanks @vidulaJ

Comment: Great! Good to know!

Comment: Thanks @vidulaJ, you really helped me too :)

Answer (score 1):

To start a new activity by clicking a listitem, set an onClickListener for your ListView an start an activity from there like this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
           Blog blog= (Blog ) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
           Intent intent = new Intent();
 // use intent.putExtras() for die kind of information you want to deliver
           getApplicationContext.startActivity(intent,yourActivity.class)

            }
        });
```

Comment: EDIT: Changed parent.getItemAtPosition(position) ... to adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position) , now its correct